# Header moves off screen after PHP Steam Login

Tags: html, css

I have installed a Steam API login system to my website. After successful login, I have a set redirection back to my home page.

After this is successful, my CSS Header moves down off of the screen. I've tried moving images around etc, but seem to be unsuccessful.

```
#header nav li {
            -moz-animation: nav-icons 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
            -webkit-animation: nav-icons 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
            -o-animation: nav-icons 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
            -ms-animation: nav-icons 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
            animation: nav-icons 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            display: inline-block;
            height: 5.35em;
            line-height: 5.885em;
            opacity: 0;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            width: 5.35em;
```

Site is: http://csgoedge.com/

```
// We use POST to logout so people can't embed images to the logout function and annoy people.
echo "<form method=\"POST\"><input type=\"image\" src=\"images/logout.png\" id=\"logout\" name=\"logout\" value=\"Logout\" /></form>";

}else{

// Display login button
echo "<a href=\"" . $auth->GetLoginURL() . "\"><img src=\"SteamAuth/assets/sits_large_noborder.png\" id=\"login\" alt=\"Sign in through Steam\" /></a>";
}
```

Comment: This smells like a var_dump, echo or something similar in your code is outputting garbage at the top of your page, did you check the source to find out?

Comment: I can post the PHP source if you'd like.

Comment: No need, we offer ideas for you to check, if you were able to implement the login api, you should be able to check the source to see if something is leading your HTML at the top. Check your whole source is irelevant for us and a waste of time

Comment: That's alright, Im having a look around now, I just can't seem to find much that's messing with the main div.

Comment: After reviewing your html code, i see that the form is causing the problem. I will move this to HTML/CSS tags as this has nothing to do with PHP anymore and is pure html/css question.

Comment: Thanks dude. I'll have a look around I guess